# DatePicker days cut off

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to have a AlertDialog modal with a DatePicker inside of it. However, when I add the DatePicker to the modal in the editor, the bottom dates are cut off:
[image]

And sure enough, when running on the emulator, the bottom row of dates are cut off:

[image]

I've tried making the padding and margin and even height greater but nothing works.

EDIT: Below is my XML code for the modal with the DatePicker.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dose_date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your XML code?

Comment: The calendar view is in a `ScrollView` if I'm correct. Did you try scrolling them up / down?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is in a `ScrollView` under the hood, but I do not have it in a `ScrollView`. I tried scrolling on the calendar but I am unable to scroll it up/down.

Comment: Also @YunusKulyyev my XML code is posted above.

Comment: Where is your calendar date picker. The one that you have posted is only for the spinner picker

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, did anyone solve it?

Comment: Why are these widgets not fully customizable?  It looks like a poor quality engineering and design to me on Google's part...

Answer (score 1):

Just use `CalendarView` instead of `DatePicker`. It doesn't have that bug.

Answer (score 1):

Found a working solution to this.
A little description of the problem here. DatePicker uses [this layout](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_legacy.xml#L77-L78) for calendar view:

```
    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="245dip"
        android:layout_height="280dip"
```

Basically a fixed width and height. This used to work correctly with the `holo` theme i.e. `android:Theme.Holo.Light` since it uses a [legacy xml layout](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/calendar_view.xml), but with appcompat theme or material theme, it started to cut off the last line in the calendar, since they're using a [different layout](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/day_picker_content_material.xml).

The solution is to update the calendarview height programmatically and make it wrap content.

```
CalendarView cv = datePicker.getCalendarView();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) cv.getLayoutParams();
params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; // Or 300dp
cv.setLayoutParams(params);
```